# coreML Hand Pose classification: doesn't appear on the camera

Tags: swiftui, classification, arkit, coreml, createml

I created a Hand Pose model using CreateML and integrated it into my SwiftUI project app.

While coding, I referred to the Apple Developer documentation app for the necessary code.

However, when I ran the app on an iPhone 14, the camera didn't display any effects or finger numbers as expected.

by using ARKit and CoreML:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let arViewController: ARViewController
    let model: modelHand

    
    func modelHand() {
        let model = modelHand()
        
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) -> ARViewController {
        arViewController.model = model
        return arViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ARViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) {
    }
}

class ARViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    var frameCounter = 0
    let handPosePredictionInterval = 10
    var model: modelHand!
    var effectNode: SCNNode?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let arView = ARSCNView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(arView)
        
        let session = ARSession()
        session.delegate = self
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.frameSemantics = .personSegmentationWithDepth
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
        let handPoseRequest = VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest()
        handPoseRequest.maximumHandCount = 1
        handPoseRequest.revision = VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequestRevision1
        
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:])
        
        do {
            try handler.perform([handPoseRequest])
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Hand Pose Request failed: \(error)")
        }
        
        guard let handPoses = handPoseRequest.results, !handPoses.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        if frameCounter % handPosePredictionInterval == 0 {
            if let handObservation = handPoses.first as? VNHumanHandPoseObservation {
                do {
                    let keypointsMultiArray = try handObservation.keypointsMultiArray()
                    let handPosePrediction = try model.prediction(poses: keypointsMultiArray)
                    let confidence = handPosePrediction.labelProbabilities[handPosePrediction.label]!
                    
                    print("Confidence: \(confidence)")
                    
                    if confidence > 0.9 {
                        print("Rendering hand pose effect: \(handPosePrediction.label)")
                        renderHandPoseEffect(name: handPosePrediction.label)
                    }
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failed to perform hand pose prediction: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func renderHandPoseEffect(name: String) {
        switch name {
        case "One":
            print("Rendering effect for One")
            if effectNode == nil {
                effectNode = addParticleNode(for: "One")
            }
        default:
            print("Removing all particle nodes")
            removeAllParticleNode()
        }
    }
    
    func removeAllParticleNode() {
        effectNode?.removeFromParentNode()
        effectNode = nil
    }
    
    func addParticleNode(for poseName: String) -> SCNNode {
        print("Adding particle node for pose: \(poseName)")
        let particleNode = SCNNode()
        return particleNode
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let model = modelHand()

    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer(arViewController: ARViewController(), model: model)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some constraints, also the controller should be created in the make function

Comment: I add a constraints and the controller are on the make func, unfortunately nothing happen on the camera 'func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) -> ARViewController {
        let controller = ARViewController()
        controller.model = model
        arViewController.arView = controller.arView
        return controller
    }'

Comment: Mmmm that looks a little off…